# Get output layer Tensorflow 1.14

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I want to create an multi-modal machine learning model using TLSTM for time-variant data.
In order to concatinate time-variant with time-invariant data I need to get the output vector of the TLSTM.
I´m using this TLSTM Model: https://github.com/illidanlab/T-LSTM
I updated the repo to be compatible with Tensorflow 1.14 and Python 3.7.12.

I assume you can exreact the output vector at the get_output function:

```
    def get_output(self, state):
        output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(state, self.Wo) + self.bo)
        output = tf.nn.dropout(output, self.keep_prob)
        output = tf.matmul(output, self.W_softmax) + self.b_softmax
        return output
```

If I print the output I get an tensor:

```
output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(state, self.Wo) + self.bo)
print(output)
-> Tensor("map_5/while/Relu:0", shape=(?, 64), dtype=float32)
print(output[0])
-> Tensor("map_5/while/strided_slice:0", shape=(64,), dtype=float32)
print(output[0, 0])
-> Tensor("map_5/while/strided_slice_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

The 64 dimension seems to be the output I´m looking for, how can I access it?

**Solution: tf.print()**

Note that inside of a session it must be called as control_dependence:

```
    def get_output(self, state):
        output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(state, self.Wo) + self.bo)
        print_op = tf.print(
            output,
            summarize=-1,
            output_stream="file://C:/Users/my_path/T-LSTM-master/features/foo.out")
        with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
            output = tf.nn.dropout(output, self.keep_prob)
            output = tf.matmul(output, self.W_softmax) + self.b_softmax
            return output
```

This example directly saves the feature as a file. Summarize=-1 to save/print the entire tensor.

Comment: How do you include TSLSTM.py in your code where you want to use the get_output? Can you share a little bit of your code? Or do you just use the main of the github you provided?

Comment: You can find my main here: https://github.com/Jandevmi/T-LSTM/blob/AKI_async/main.py  
I added an early stopping with a validation set to training.
The testing part, which should be the part to access the output layer, is doing the same as the original code.

Comment: But when you can print the output why can't you access it?
If it helps i can write an answer how to call the function and save the return value in a variable but i assume that this isn't your problem or am i mistaken?

Comment: That is kind of my problem.
I´m very new to Tensorflow and don't know how to access the actual values of the vector. Most solutions I find are already working with Keras.  
If I have the values, it should be no problem for me to pass to the main.

Comment: What do you want to do with the values? just print them or use them in another function as a tensor?

Comment: I updated the print statements I tried. They return a description about the tensor, but not the actual values. I´m lacking the knowledge about correctly working with tensors.
When talking about values I´m thinking about a vector like: x = [0.390, 0.643, -0.123, 1.456, ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print your `output` tensor, most of the time `tf.print(output)` would give you the required result.

Comment: I tried to use tf.print(output), but it didn´t write anything to the console. I could solve it now: Inside of a session tf.print() needs to be called as control_dependencie. I´ll add the solution to my post.
Thanks for your help!